# SearchCriteria Logical OR and AND search

Tags: magento2, collection, search-criteria

I am trying to get a search criteria to become the following SQL:

```
WHERE (a = 1 AND b = 2) OR (c = 3)
```

Magento2 Documentation only has the [example](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html#logical-and-and-or-search) where AND and OR are reversed. Is this even possible? It doesn't seem like it is.

Comment: By default: NO, Where you want?

Comment: In a custom repository.

Comment: Then easy to create what you want. Show your code, then will be easy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property

> Distribution of disjunction over conjunction
>
> P or (Q and R) <-> (P or Q) and (P or R)

So, you can transform you criteria to

> WHERE (a = 1 OR c = 3) AND (b = 2 OR c = 3)

Comment: I needed to add another condition to the first part which makes it double distribution and I end up with 4 sets. It is not really readable but I guess it is better than having two collections.